# Visual Studio - cannot add to toolbox AnyCPU DLL with reference to 32bit dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll, 64-bit

We have existing API that includes UI controls (both WinForms and WPF) dll that shipped with our product. it is in use by our clients for a while for 32bit.

Recentaly, our customers moved to 64bit versions and we're trying to provide support for developers with 64bit version, as Visual studio is 32bit process, and our controls dll has depenencies with native 64bit dlls. our controls cannot be loaded/displayed in toolbox/designer.

In order to solve this problem. I changed the output type of the controls dll to be AnyCPU, also wrapped any references to a lower native dlls in order to prevent exceptions when dragging controls to designer, or when loading existing forms/windows.
and indeed, its solves the problem of dragging controls to designer/loading existing forms/windows. but that's because I have already loaded controls in the toolbox, from previous 32 bit version.

We still have a problem loading the controls to the toolbox (Toolbox->Choose Items)
in VS2010 - cannot add at all, the failure is due to lower native dll that cannot be load.
in VS2012 - Winforms controls are able to be loaded (sometimes only after the second time),
 WPF controls NOT being able to be load at all.

Does anyone understand the loading dll mechanism of Visual Studio?
Any other suggestion/workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that VS will try to load any referenced DLLs including C++ ones when adding .Net DLLs to toolbox, even if we will never request lower DLLs resources in designer run-time,

The workaround we use - supplying also the 32bit dlls version of our controls framework, the one that are referenced by the .Net dlls.
open a project, add reference to the 64bit version of your application.
open toolbox, add dlls, now refer to the 32bit version.